# Make Bootstrap header image "lock" at the top of the section below it

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

http://www.wearethefirehouse.com/wcftest/

The header background image is 'floating' under the top of the section below it when the window is expanded. if you bring the browser window in you can see the images have about half of them left under the top of the lower "About" section.

How can I edit the CSS to "lock" the bottom of that background image so it doesn't slide under? (The gradient at the base of the BG image should always be against the brown for that effect basically.)

Here's the CSS:

```
.intro {
display: table;
width: 100%;
padding: 100px 0;
text-align: center;
color: #0000;
background: url(../img/intro-bg5.jpg) no-repeat top center;
background-color: #000;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover; }
```

Comment: how did you imagine the rest of the content to come together with the lower sections of the BG? do you want the BG image to become the BG image of the lower sections too up until it finishes with the gradient...?

Answer (score 0):

Change the css to:

Add `margin-top: 56px;` to `.intro` section

```
.intro {
display: table;
width: 100%;
padding: 100px 0;
text-align: center;
color: #0000;
background: url(../img/intro-bg5.jpg) no-repeat top center;
background-color: #000;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
margin-top: 56px;
}
```

and add `margin-top: 0;` to `.intro` in the `@media (min-width: 767)` section:

```
@media (min-width: 767px)
.intro {
height: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin-top: 0px;
}
```

But as stated in webeno's answer, this doesn't fix your gradient problem.

Comment: i did not edit any values, just added the "back quotes" so code is formatted properly... ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the BG image is setup for the header only, thus the next section will always cover it, unless you remove `background-size: cover;` and set the height of your header to the height of your image.

This way however, the image wouldn't expand anymore on larger screens. To go around that, I suggest you remove the BG image from the header and add it to the body. This way the full BG image will always show up until it naturally finishes with the gradient (that I see you "hard edited" on the image itself).

Alternatively you could create the gradient effect with css on the bottom of the header section using `linear-gradient`.

Here is an implementation doing this with CSS gradients (note: here too, I moved the BG image to the body element):

```css
* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0
}

body {
    background: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200/") no-repeat;
}

header {
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(92, 78, 55, 1), rgba(92, 78, 55, 0));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(92, 78, 55, 1), rgba(92, 78, 55, 0));
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(92, 78, 55,0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(92, 78, 55,1)));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(92, 78, 55, 1), rgba(92, 78, 55, 0));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(92, 78, 55, 1), rgba(92, 78, 55, 0));
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(92, 78, 55, 1), rgba(92, 78, 55, 0));
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='rgba(92, 78, 55, 1)', endColorstr='rgba(92, 78, 55, 0)', GradientType=1);
    height:100px;
    width:400px;
}

section {
    background-color:#5C4E3B;
    height:100px;
    width:400px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header></header>
    <section></section>
</body>
```

Comment: Sorry guys. None of these worked... in fact they made the problem worse. Even MORE of the image was tucked in. Didn't even bother uploading them.

Comment: I was hoping for the bottom of the second row of images to butt right up against the top of the beige section below.

Comment: yeah, but they are, if you use one of my above selected methods... you cannot allow the images to expand / become bigger but at the same time keep the same height, that's just physically impossible :)